# Subscribe to complete model in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, subscription, subscribe

I have an view model with a lot of attributes and I want to detect any changes in order to store the model into my database.

I don´t want to subscribe to every single attribute, but to all at once

My approach with jQuery does not work at all

```
var MyModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.myMember1 = ko.observable(1);
    this.myMember2 = ko.observable(1);
    this.myMember3 = ko.observable(1);
    .....



     $.each(this, function (member, value) {
        member.subscribe(saveModel());
    })

}
```

Is there any known solution for my problem?

Comment: can you explain your question?

Comment: `var self=this` declared and i'm amused why you referring to `this.` rather using `self.`

Comment: tried everything, this was just the last version before giving up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback for `$.each` will receive property name as 1st argument and property value as second. So in your case, `member` is the property name and `value` is the observable value. Also subscribe need a function and what you give it is the result of a function call.

So you need either:

```
$.each(this, function (member, value) {
    if(ko.isObservable(self[member])) {
        self[member].subscribe(saveModel); // saveModel not saveModel()
    }
});
```

or

```
$.each(this, function (member, value) {
    if(ko.isObservable(value)) {
        value.subscribe(saveModel); // saveModel not saveModel()
    }
});
```

If `saveModel` is also a member of `MyModel`, it should be referenced as `self.saveModel`.